# Delete an object in core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have an entity in my core data model like this:

```
@interface Selection : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * book_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * contenu;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * page_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * nbrOfOccurences;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * next;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * previous;
```

I have created many `Selection`s and saved them in Core Data and now I would like to delete some selections with some criteria. For example, I would like to delete a `Selection` object if matches the following:

```
content = test
page_id = 5
book_id = 1331313
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

What **Mike Weller** wrote is right. I'll expand the answer a little bit.

First you need to create a `NSFetchRequest` like the following:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];    
[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Selection" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
```

Then you have to set the predicate for that request like the following:

```
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"content == %@ AND page_id == %@ AND book_id == %@", contentVal, pageVal, bookVal]];
```

where

```
NSString* contentVal = @"test";
NSNumber* pageVal = [NSNumber numberWithInt:5];
NSString* bookVal = @"1331313";
```

I'm using `%@` since I'm supposing you are using objects and not scalar values.

Now you perform a fetch in the context with the previous request:

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSArray* results = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

`results` contains all the managed objects that match that predicate.

Finally you could grab the objects and call a deletion on them.

```
[context deleteObject:currentObj];
```

Once done you need to save the context as per the documentation.

> Just as a new object is not saved to the store until the context is saved, a deleted object is not removed from the store until the context is saved.

Hence

```
NSError* error = nil;
[context save:&error];
```

Note that `save` method returns a bool value. So you can use an approach like the following or display an alert to the user. Source [NSManagedObjectContext save error](http://matthewmorey.com/nsmanagedobjectcontext-save-error/).

```
NSError *error = nil;
if ([context save:&error] == NO) {
    NSAssert(NO, @"Save should not fail\n%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    abort();
}
```

Comment: @flexaddicted This should be edited to include the `[context save:&error]` call that needs to take place, or else the deleted object doesn't get removed from the store.  In addition, if you're using a persistent store, it has to get saved like so: `[context saveToPersistentStore:&error]`.

Comment: @EvanR Modified my answer taking into account your comment.

Comment: It's worth adding `fetchRequest.includesPropertyValues = NO;` in the setup so that the objects arrive more cheaply as faults.

Answer (score 5):

You should perform a fetch request using an `NSPredicate` with the appropriate conditions, and then call the `deleteObject:` method on `NSManagedObjectContext` with each object in the result set.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Mike Weller and flexaddicted, after calling `[context deleteObject:currentObj];` you need to `save:` context:

```
NSError *error = nil;
[context save:&error];
```

As from [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdCreateMOs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001654-SW1):

> Just as a new object is not saved to the store until the context is saved, a deleted object is not removed from the store until the context is saved.

That made matter in my case.

Comment: This is definitely necessary—I suggested it as an edit to the accepted answer.