# How to delete data in core data database?

Tags: ios, core-data

Here is my code which I am using for the table view controller. Issue is that rows are not deleted and are not displayed in my table view?
what should I do in order to remove my data from the coredata database as well in my row?

How can I do this using my code below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self fetchdata];
}
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self fetchdata];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
-(void)fetchdata
{
    self.fetchrequest=[[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Student" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    [_fetchrequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error;
    self.fetchedobjects=[_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:_fetchrequest error:&error];
    if (_fetchedobjects != nil)
    {
        _studentattributes=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:_fetchedobjects];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return _studentattributes.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellreuse" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    _STUDENT=[_studentattributes objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text=_STUDENT.name;

    _namearray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self.namearray addObject:_STUDENT.name];
    _classarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self.classarray addObject:_STUDENT.standard];
    _sectionarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self.sectionarray addObject:_STUDENT.section];
    _rollarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self.rollarray addObject:_STUDENT.roll];

    return cell;
}
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"seguereuse"])
    {
        EnterDetailViewController *enterdetail=(EnterDetailViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        enterdetail.managedObjectContext=self.managedObjectContext;
    }

    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"seguedisplay"])
    {
         NSIndexPath *indexpath=[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        DisplayViewController *display=(DisplayViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        display.studentdetails=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[_namearray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row],[_classarray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row],[_sectionarray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row],[_rollarray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row], nil];
    }
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {

       [_managedObjectContext deleteObject:[_studentattributes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


       [self.tableview reloaddata];

            }
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert)
    {

    }

}
```

now how to sort out the issue?

Comment: Delete the object from your _studentattributes array as well after deleting the record from coredata. Also reload your tableview.

Comment: @AdeelMiraj Its deleting but when i am running the app again its showing the same row again

Comment: refer to the answer in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482311/delete-an-object-in-core-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way in a view based table view is to delete the object from the database, from the content array and from the table view in an update block.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
       [tableView beginUpdates];
       NSManagedObject *objectToDelete = [_studentattributes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       [_managedObjectContext deleteObject: objectToDelete];
       [_studentattributes removeObject: objectToDelete];
       [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
       [tableView endUpdates];
       NSError *error;
       [_managedObjectContext save:&error];
       if (error) {
         NSLog(@"An error occurred while deleting a row: %@", error);
       }
    }
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: sir, still its not deleting only its removing from the table. but whenever i start running my app in the simmulator,it again displays the data.

Comment: is the method called at all?

Comment: which method are talking about sir

Comment: `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath::`

Comment: PS: sorry I didn't get that the row is removed from that table view. To delete the object permanently from the database you have to save and commit the database before quitting the app with `save:error:` called on the managedObjectContext

Comment: where should i call that. sir, the basic intention of mine is that when the user swipes the respective table row it would offer hiom a delete button clicking on which it would delete the row from the table as well as the database. and as far as i know the method tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:: is automatically executed when user swipes the row. so i think what for i need to call that. and if you suggest so kindly say me how to do so. sir please provide me the coding for your above mentioned suggestion so that i can implement it. Thanks for your answer

Comment: sir can you please explain me the meaning of this block of your coding-[tableView beginUpdates];
       NSManagedObject *objectToDelete = [_studentattributes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       [_managedObjectContext deleteObject: objectToDelete];
       [_studentattributes removeObject: objectToDelete];
       [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
       [tableView endUpdates];

Comment: the `begin/endUpdates` block ensures to keep the data source and table view in sync while altering data. It's actually not needed with one `insert/remove/move` action, but it's good habit to provide it. It's also recommended to alter the data in the datasource always before the table view. The other lines delete/remove the object from the source respectively.

Comment: oh thank you again sir.....sir can i call this function in any other function if i want. if so then how?

Comment: You can use the code wherever you want assuming you have a reference to the table view, the data source and the managedObjectContext.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are holding a strong reference to the `fetchedObjects` and after you delete it you only reload the table view.

Plus you are not calling the `managedObjectContext` to persist/save the changes

So your code should be more like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {

       [_managedObjectContext deleteObject:[_studentattributes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
       [_managedObjectContext save:nil]; // Tell the context to save the changes.

       [self fetchdata]; // Needs to fetch data again so your _studentattributes you have the right count.

       [self.tableview reloaddata];

    }
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert)
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: Sir, another problem is showing that i have used a disclosure identifier to show the detail in a view controller but its not showing the details of the row which i have cliked but its only showing the details of my recently entered data

Comment: @Abhisek Hi, i did not clearly understand how it is related to the original question. If you need help on that matter I would suggest you to either open a new question with this specific problem or edit this very one and explain every problem you are facing.

Comment: okay sir you please answer the question which i have asked in this one. Sir, the problem is my data is not being permanently deleted from the database. its showing again when i am running the simulator once again.

Comment: yes sir, Its working. i have did the mistake by not using the method  save:error to permanently delete the row. thanks for your effort & thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I see you are calling `fetchdata` multiple times. I would advise you to call it once in `loadView` and then call `[self.tableview reloadData]` in `viewWillAppear`. Also notice you are calling `reloaddata` and not `reloadData` on your table view.

Next, manage object context is a scratch pad where you can make changes. But ultimately you need to save it by calling:

```
if (![context save:&error]) {
     NSLog(@"Couldn't save: %@", error);
}
```

**PS: I am assuming based on your comment to Adeel that your data source `_studentattributes` is getting updated properly before you call `reloadData` on your table view again as that would drive the table view look and feel.**